# macOS (& BSD?): Why won't "ls -R" from root directory list files in a subdirectory?

Tags: macos, unix

macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

```
cd /usr/bin
ls grep
grep
```

However...

```
cd /
ls -R grep
ls: grep: No such file or directory
```

Why?  Workaround?

If I use `ls -R / | grep grep` that "brute force" approach works - but not ideal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133764/discussion-on-question-by-esp-macos-bsd-why-wont-ls-r-from-root-direct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ls lists the things that are passed in as non option arguments (that is the things that do not begin with `-`)

From ls man page

> For each operand that names a file of a type other than directory, ls
> displays its name as well as any requested, associated information.  For
> each operand that names a file of type directory, ls displays the names of
> files contained within that directory, as well as any requested, associated
> information.

The -R option recursed into the directories that are passed to ls. In this case it is looking for a directory or file named grep - and if there is a directory named grep in the root it will list all files and directories under grep. (There will be permission issues so not a clean as that)

What you are trying to do is find the file grep when you do not know what directory it is in.

The ls command to do that is as you show `ls -R /` which looks at all files and directories under root. However it shows a lot and so you have to filter that which grep will partially do, there could be false positives for files like fgrep

A better simple Unix command to do what you want is find

So what you are after is

```
find / -name grep
```

On my Monterey system I get a lot of directories which I am not allowed to search
e.g.
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied

But I do get the relevant output

```
/usr/bin/grep
```

The errors can be hidden by just looking at stdout and sending stderr to /dev/null

```
find / -name grep 2>/dev/null
```

giving

```
/usr/bin/grep
```